# HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported php curl

Tags: php, apache, http, curl, paypal

I am attempting to implement PayPal's future payment server (https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/docs/future_payments_server.md), but am running into an issue with my server platform.

Whenever I try to curl with this code:

```
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
);

$userpwd = "CLIENT_ID:SECRET";

$ch = curl_init("https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code&response_type=token&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&code=".$code);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $userpwd);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I get the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Date: Wed, 22 Oct 2014 21:30:35 GMT
Connection: close
```

What could be causing this issue, and how do I configure my server to support this curl code?

Thanks

UPDATE: new code

```
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
);
$fp = fopen("db.txt","w");
$data = array(
    "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
    "response_type" => "token",
    "redirect_uri" => "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob",
    "code" => $code
);
$query = http_build_query($data);
$ch = curl_init("https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token?".$query);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $userpwd);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_NONE);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fwrite($fp,$response);
fclose($fp);
```

new error message:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 PROXY_SERVER_INFO: host=slcjavapapi3027a.slc.paypal.com;threadId=XXXX Paypal-Debug-Id: 679a3452b9bad Pragma: No-cache Cache-Control: no-cache Expires: Wed, 31 Dec 1969 16:00:00 PST SERVER_INFO: identitysecuretokenserv:v1.oauth2.token&CalThreadId=XXXXX&TopLevelTxnStartTime=149489a7468&Host=slcidensectoken3043a.slc.paypal.com&pid=XXXXX Content-Language: * Date: Sat, 25 Oct 2014 18:38:41 GMT Connection: close Content-Type: text/xml Content-Length: 0 Connection: close
```

Comment: instead of putting all your arguments in the get string, put them in an array and use http_build_query to create the get string. I've seen this issue when there are some characters that should be url_encoded but aren't. Browsers usually take care of this transparently for us, curl doesn't.

Comment: You could also try to change the http version and see if that helps. http://php.net/curl_setopt has a CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION setting that you could try.

Comment: should I set it to 2.0? curl_setop($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0);

Comment: I would suggest 1.0, but you could try any. It would be quickest to just change it, run it and see the result.

Comment: Okay I tried 1.0, 1.1, 2.0 and NONE and the error did not change

Comment: I also tried using http_build_query, and I got more feedback in the error message, but its still the same error